# Ошибка при установке postgersql server

Tags: sql, postgresql

При попитке установить postgresql сервер видает ошибку смотрел видео на ютуб питался не получается. Создавал на диску C отдельную папку PostreSQL и все права всем пользователям давал и туда устанавливал но все время видает ошибку. Вот фото ошибки [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

1. **Запускаем установка от пользователя с правами администратора**.
2. Выбираем папку для установки в Program files (по умолчанию)
3. Создаём папку для для данных за пределами Program files, например C:/Postgres

Comment: Не помагает та самая ошибка